# How to create dSYM file in XCode 4?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, xcode4

Can you please let me know how can I create .dSYM file using XCode 4?

Thanks!

Answer (score 101, accepted):

If you archive the application the dsym file is in the xarchive. Right-click on the entry in the organizer, do "show in finder", right click on the xarchive and choose "show package contents". The dsym is in the dSYMs directory.

Comment: Can you rewrite the question in correct English please? I really do not understand what you ask.

Comment: I meant what if I don't archive it from xcode? but I found it inside one of the folders. (I build it with jenkins). Thanks for trying to help

Comment: Ah ok. Well seems you found the answer :) we also do command line builds here btw.

Answer (score 39):

Update for Xcode 4.3.1

For me there was 2 build settings I had to edit and I had to edit them in the PROJECT and in the TARGETS sections before XCODE would generate dSYMs.

1) Build Settings -> Build Options -> Debug Information Format = DWARF with dSYM

2) Build Settings -> Apple LLVM compilier 3.1 - Code Generation -> Generate Debug Symbols = YES

Hopefully this will help someone else because I spent a few hours banging my head against the wall with Archives that had empty dSYM directories... I "love" XCODE sometimes....

Comment: Apparently (Xcode 4.5.1) DEBUG_INFORMATION -> Deployment has setting "DWARF" by default, the other option is "DWARF with dSYM File", which is the option I'd have liked. Now I have no dSYM file, but I do have a crash report. Not nice.

Comment: Choose 'DWARF with with dSYM File'.

Comment: Generate Debug Symbols = YES that  helped me too for some reason the previous team deactivated it..

Comment: Some more related build flags: `STRIP_INSTALLED_PRODUCT`, `UNSTRIPPED_PRODUCT`, `COPY_PHASE_STRIP`

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you have selected "DWARF with dSYM File" as the Debug Information Format in the build settings of your application. The dSYM is then generated automatically when you build and is usually placed in the same folder as the resulting .app.

Answer (score 0):

You can locate .dSYM and application binary file in archive.

1. Select **Window -> Organizer**

[image: Step 1]

2. This will open up Organizer window containing last created Archive of project
3. Right click on Archive and select '**Show in Finder**'
   [image: Step 3]
4. Select '**Show Package Content**' for archive
   [image: Step 4]
5. Project.xcarchive contains **dSYMs, Info.plist and Products**
   [image: Step 5]

dSYMs folder contains dSYM file of your project.

Application folder in Project contains application binary of your project.

Answer (score -1):

You can find dSYM in Product, see below images:

1. Right click to your App > Show in Finder

[image: get dSYM - 1]

2. Here is it.

[image: get dSYM - 2]

3. If you use Crashlytics , you need to zip it then upload it to dashboard.

[image]