# (iphone) save dsym or any other file to view crash log?

Tags: iphone, crash, submission

I'm submitting my first iphone application.
I read that apple provides crash-log reports.

In order to utilize the provided crash-log,
or for any other purposes,
Do I need to save anything before I modify source to prepare update?

and a related question,
When will I be able to submit an update?
right after apple change the status to "Ready for Sale"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to save the DSYM for the version you're submitting to symbolize the crash logs. I'd also save the app binary. Last, you should somehow tag or otherwise mark the version in your version control system.

Comment: for xcode4 users, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745391/how-to-create-dsym-file-in-xcode-4, and for svn users, http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch04s06.html