# Symbolicate iPhone app crash

Tags: iphone, ios, symbolicatecrash

Symbolicate iPhone app crash - Map hexadecimal addresses to valid function namespace (call stack)

Listing requirements: Symbolicating crashes

1. Using Xcode Organizer
2. Using external services
3. Using .crash file and .dSYM file
    Sources: iTunesConnect crash report (distributed)
   Device crash log or external services.

Comment: Its a post rather a question. I apologize if I am supposed not to do this way. I felt its informative. So did.

Comment: Thanks for sharing; please make a real question about the problem your post solves, and put the solution into an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 4):

Provided I have .crash file and .dSYM file, this works.

1. **Preliminary**

   Create a folder `temp` in `~/`, path is `~/temp/`
   Keep all files in `~/temp/` i.e. script, .ipa, .dsym and .crash (in fact .ipa is not needed)
2. **Go to** `~/temp/`
3. **Set path**: If there are two Xcode's in system or paths not being set

   `sudo /usr/bin/xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/`
    `export DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app`
4. **Create shortcut**

   Alias symbolicateCrash /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDeviceKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash
5. **Get symbolication**:

   ```
   atos -arch armv7 -o 'appname.app'.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/'appname' 0x0029c296
   atos -arch armv7 -o 'appname.app'.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/'appname -l "binary image line of crash log"
   ```

   or

   ```
   symbolicateCrash 'logname'.crash 'appname.app'.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/'appname'
   ```
6. **Still, if any issues**?
   Still couldn't link with some not found, couldn't figure out exceptions.
   Downloaded script: external shell script (uploaded as 'symbolicatecrash')

`./symbolicatecrash -v filename.crash`

References:

> [How to Manually Symbolicate iOS Crash to View Crash Logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832900/how-to-manually-symbolicate-ios-crash-to-view-crash-logs/8648232#8648232)
>
> [Symbolicating iPhone App Crash Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports)
>
> [iphone: Where the .dSYM file is located in crash report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7088771/iphone-where-the-dsym-file-is-located-in-crash-report)
>
> [How to create dSYM file in XCode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745391/how-to-create-dsym-file-in-xcode-4)
>
> [How to symbolicate iPhone \ iPad crash logs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8172887/how-to-symbolicate-iphone-ipad-crash-logs)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73679651/7769239

Answer (score 0):

you should go with -->Xcode -- > Organizer--> Devices --> Device Logs :)

Here you can find crash log.... OR you can use TestFlight SDK for use see crash log of your testing teams Device....

Comment: That is when you are developing. But i guess it wont be applicable to the app released on app store. For such a case this works.

Comment: For testFlight yes it works only when you develoing the app......but xcode organiser method will works also for app store appss...

Comment: You are saying opening .crash file with xcode organizer will symbolicate? Because once we distribute app on app store we cant access devices but somehow we can access crash report.