# How to symbolicate crash logs sent from apple reviewers?

Tags: ios, crash, xcode6, symbolicatecrash, symbolicate

I have recently submitted an app to the app store and it has gotten rejected. The app I made was specifically iPhone only, however i was unaware that you had to make sure it ran on an iPad as well (Apple Guidelines 2.10) and hence my app was rejected due to it crashing when the reviewers ran it on an iPad Air.

I do not own an iPad Air so I cannot replicate the crash on my side.
The reviewers have sent me a .crash file for the app and I'm having troubles trying to symbolicate it.

I have the .crash file as well as both the .dSYM and the .app files for the app's binary. how do I go about symbolicating the .crash file from here?

Comment: For the solution you shared, +1, great :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, my suggestions :-

1) You can use Crashlytics SDK to get your crash reports in detail, its a very good crash reporter and free also. you will get the stack trace and even crash line.

2) It is not compulsory to make the app for both iPhone and iPad. If you have made the app Universal, then also you can set the app target device to iPhone only. If the user run on iPad, it will run as iPhone only. You can change the settings on Project Navigator -> Target ->General Tab -> Deployment Info -> Devices.

For info about apple guideline 2.10: iPhone apps must also run on iPad without modification, at iPhone resolution, and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution

For analyzing Crash report :-
Check out these links :-
1) [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports)
2) [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15064368/symbolicate-iphone-app-crash)

Comment: update: the 2nd link you gave me didnt work :( however the first link had an answer that helped explain a few things that made sense to me. I think i'm rather close to being able to symbolicate the crash log. 

The problem im having now that i found out was that the crash log belong to a binary with a different UUID compared to the ones that i used to attempt to symbolicate it with hence its possible that it failed to symbolicate because of this. will update again after more troubleshooting

Comment: UPDATE: i did it! i managed to symbolicate the file finally!!! the problem was the UUID for the crash logs were referring to another version of the binary after finding the right binary for the crash log it all worked! I wouldn't have done it without the 1st link you sent me! cheers man

Comment: the answer by Andreas Klöber in Link 1 was the one that helped me understand the concept of how to symbolicate. I also used this link that i found somewhere online (i forgot): https://github.com/robovm/robovm/wiki/Symbolicate-a-crash-reports   
these 2 links taught me how to symbolicate as well as a few concepts behind how it works. Hope it'll help anyone whos stuck at symbolicating

Comment: If any answer helps you also, you should  upvote it also by clicking on the up arrow of the answer like you mentioned Andreas Klöber or mine too :P

Comment: I would! but i dont have 15 Rep unfortunately :( still new to this site

Answer (score 15):

Some info for people that are having similar issues: we received the crash log files as `txt` files. If you change the extension to `crash` you can just drag and drop the files in Xcode:

Connect any device, open `Window/Devices`, click on `View Device Logs` and drag and drop the .crash files there and they will symbolicate automatically.

I couldn't get ours to symbolicate manually, even with `atos` and by using the correct `dSYM` file (checked the UUID). However Xcode managed to symbolicate them.

Disclaimer: This is tested on Xcode 8.1. If you stumble on this answer when running Xcode 9/10/... there is (as usual) no guarantee this will still work.

Comment: Thank you Joris Mans, your method is simple and very effective to symbolicate the crash file .txt, that return from app review board. I confirm it works well with xcode Version 8.3.3 (8E3004b)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73679651/7769239